# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'student'

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

> This is the controller class

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/editstd/{id}")  
    public String edit(@ModelAttribute("student") @PathVariable int id, Model m){  
    /* Student s1=new Student();   
     Student std= studentService.editStudent(id);*/ 
        m.addAttribute("student",studentService.editStudent(id));

        return "studentEdit";  
    } 

 @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
    public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student){  
        studentService.updateStudent(student); 
        return "redirect:/userDetails";  
    }
```

> This is the jsp view

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>  
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>  

        <h1>Edit Student</h1>
       <form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="student" action="/quaris/editsave">  
        <table >  
         <tr>  
          <td>userName : </td> 
          <td><form:input path="username"  /></td>
         </tr>  
         <tr>  
          <td>Password :</td>  
          <td><form:input path="password" /></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>  
          <td> </td>  
          <td><input type="submit" value="Edit Save" /></td>  
         </tr>  
        </table>  

       </form:form>
```

> Full Stack Trace

```
    Jun 13, 2019 2:59:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/quaris] threw exception [An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/jsp/studentEdit.jsp] at line [11]

8:          <table >  
9:          <tr>  
10:           <td>userName : </td> 
11:           <td><form:input path="username"  /></td>
12:          </tr>  
13:          <tr>  
14:           <td>Password :</td>  


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'student' available as request attribute
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:177)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getName(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:163)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.autogenerateId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:148)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.resolveId(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag.writeDefaultAttributes(AbstractHtmlElementTag.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag.writeTagContent(InputTag.java:356)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:86)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:83)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.studentEdit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005finput_005f0(studentEdit_jsp.java:239)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.studentEdit_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(studentEdit_jsp.java:185)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.studentEdit_jsp._jspService(studentEdit_jsp.java:137)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:476)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:712)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:312)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:170)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1839)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I am not able to solve this error if anyone knows the solution please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Please do not only post code in your question, state your issue in details in order to receive the help you need with your code.

Comment: i am not able to edit the username and password with this logic

Comment: For starters: `public String edit(@ModelAttribute("student") @PathVariable int id, Model m){ }` >> `public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model m){ }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How can use @modelattribute and store in int variable, moreover you cant use path variable in spring mvc, its for Rest services.

If yours is normal spring mvc project

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
            public String save(@ModelAttribute("student") Student stud){    
                dao.save(stud);    
                return "redirect:/viewStudent";//will redirect to viewStudent request mapping    
            }
```

below method gives list of all student

```
        @RequestMapping("/viewStudent")    
            public String viewStudents(Model m){    
                List<Student> list=dao.getAllStudents();    
                m.addAttribute("list",list);  
               return "viewstudentpage";//where it displays all student info with edit option    
            }
```

below is to handle edit

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/editstud/{id}")    
            public String edit(@PathVariable int id, Model m){    
                Student stud=dao.getStudById(id);    
                m.addAttribute("student",stud);  
                return "studenteditform";// jsp page on clicking edit of particular student    
            }
```

on clicking save in above form, it gets new modified student object which has to be update by below code

```
        @RequestMapping(value="/editsave",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
            public String editsave(@ModelAttribute("student") Student stud){    
                dao.update(stud);    
                return "viewstudentpage";
    }
```